# add 1 to value after submission to databse with angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, ionic-framework

I'm working on a project where user can like comment made by users. and what i want to achieve is when a user likes a comment on a page by default + 1 should be added to the total comments made. Below is my script my it doesn't work

```
.controller('feedsctrl',['$scope','$http',function($scope,$http){

    $http.get('http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/like.php').success(function(data){

        //$scope.feeds = console.log(data) ;
        $scope.feeds = data;
        $scope.lovepic = function() {

            event.preventDefault();
            $http.post("http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/scripts/comment.php",
                {
                    'u_pic_id': $scope.u_pic_id,
                    'pic': $scope.pic
                }
            ).success(function(data,status,headers,config){
                 console.log(data)
                 $scope.comment_total=$scope.comment_total+1;
            });
        }
    });
}])
```

HTML

```
<ion-content>
    <div ng-controller="feedsctrl" class="list card has-subheader" ng-repeat="item in feeds">

<a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.comment_total}} Comments</a>
</ion-content>
```

Comment: More people will try to help you if you can make your code a bit neater.

Comment: Actually `item.comment_total` should be just `comment_total`. Also you must avoid `success` and `error` methods since they're deprecated. You must use **then** instead.

Comment: Where's the closing `</div>`?

Answer (score 0):

Issue with your code is that you are trying to update the $scope.data[item].comments with $scope.comments. These both are different variable in angular controller scope. you should perform the addition in the same scope variable to get it reflected on the view. You can achieve this by slight modification in your code

html

```
  <ion-content>
   <div ng-controller="feedsctrl" class="list card has-subheader" ng- repeat="item in feeds trach by $index">
    <img src="item.src" ng-click="lovepic($index)">
    <a href="#" class="subdued">{{item.comment_total}} Comments</a>
  </div>
  </ion-content>
```

in the controller.

```
   $scope.lovepic=function(index) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $http.post("http://localhost/vivalooks/app_ion/scripts/comment.php",
         {'u_pic_id':$scope.feeds[index].u_pic_id,'pic':$scope.feeds[index].pic})
         .then(function(data,status,headers,config){
          $scope.feeds[index].comment_total == undefined ? 1 : $scope.feeds[index].comment_total +1;
        });
    }
```

Comment: i get this error: Cannot read property 'u_pic_id' of undefined
    at Scope.$scope.lovepic (app.js:219)
    at fn

Comment: if you could share the feed object,  i can tell you the exact variables you need to use, currently i assumed that in feed array each item has u_pic_id and pic properties.

Comment: you mean my i generate from the comment.php?

Comment: i need the response of like.php first and the input parameters of the comment.php

Comment: these are the values returned from like.php [{"u_pic_id":"1685","pic":"image27.jpg "}, {{"u_pic_id":"1686","pic":"image28.jpg "}]

Comment: i have updated the lovepic function in the answer, based on the info provided, hope this will help you. I still see one issue that in your feed you do not have the comment_total property. Are you not saving this detail to database.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116876/discussion-between-neiza-and-deep).